# check which names have the same field in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

i have this table:

```
id name     lastname   id_op  time
0  Richard  Touch        5    8.00
1  Mattew   Cast         6    9.00
2  Carl     Cappai       7   10.00
3  Mario    Bros         8   10.00
4  Luigi    Same         9    8.00
```

I want to print in page ex:

"Richard and Luigi have the sames time: 8.00"

"Carl and Mario have the same time: 10.00"

i tryed with this choice:

```
   $link=connect_db();
$query_count="SELECT * FROM table";
$result_count=mysql_query($query_count,$link);


while($var = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_count)){


foreach ($var as $key => $value){
        $i=0;
        $var[$i];
        $row_count[$i][$key] = $value;

        //echo $content[$index][$key];
    echo $key.' '.$value.', ';


    } 

    $i++;

}

 for($i=0;$i<count($row_count);$i++) {
for($j=$i+1;$j<count($row_count);$j++) {
if($row_count[$i]['time']==$row_count[$j]['time']) {
        echo ' '.$row_count[$i]['name'].' and '.$row_count_lun[$j]['name'].'have the same time:'.$row_count_lun[$i]['time'].'';
        }
}
 }
```

Final Result = Carl Carl Richard Richard.. -__-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
select group_concat(name) as names, time
from table t
group by time
having count(*) > 1;
```

This will give you output such as:

```
Names               Time
Richard,Luigi       8:00
. . .
```

Which can then format on the application side.

Comment: You loop through it in your code and print it out however you like.

Comment: sorry but, if i have a second time field? example: Richard and mario have the same time: 8.00 - 12.00

Comment: @user3166364 . . . A second time field would be a different problem.  Ask another question, with sample data and desired results.